# Can't print "cups-pki-invalid"

Tags: printing

I can't print, print jobs stop at "pending" and it shows a status "cups-pki-invalid".  Troubleshooter couldnt fix, this is what it outputted as a log

https://pastebin.com/99JfDCWQ

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening,
after a few attempts, I removed the printer from CUPS and added it again, through the web interface (localhost:631)
It worked. I'd like to understand the root cause...
Ji

Comment: Deleting and adding the printer back using the GUI on port 631 was the only thing that worked for me, too. I hope that helps somebody else as well. Still no clue as to a root cause. :(

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to download drivers from the manufacturers website, it works now.